# When 3rd NF is not the best solution? (Performance)

Tags: mysql, database-design, eav

I have 3 tables:

```
Measurements ('id', 'name')
Records ('id', 'measurement_id', 'time', 'number') - Measurement has many records
Parameters ('id', 'record_id', 'param', 'value') - Record has many parameters
```

The problem that I have is that I need to allow end-user to import data via web page into the database and at the present moment due to:

1. INLINE FILE (MySQL)
2. Large Data files 500MB+

I am having to import measurements and records first which takes 50% of the the total parsing (import) time; After which I can populate parameters, which takes the other 50% of the time.

On other hand, If I did have not-fully normalised form of the database i would be able to parse data in one go and save 50% of the parsing time. By the way, at the present moment it takes parser about 7 minutes to parse (import) 500MB of data, with 50% time saving we are looking at 3-4 minutes for import to fully complete!

So tables would look something like:

```
Measurements ('id', 'name')
Records ('id', 'measurement_id', 'time', 'param', 'value') - Measurement has many records
```

The downside of this, of cause, is me having to repeat a data in the "time" column within "records" table, which would cost me DB space in the long run.

p.s. I can probably remove the need for the date part because I know when measurements starts and ends, so due to that I can work dates out when needed using programming language; However, it would be much more convenient for me to have "time" in the database so that i can use it for querying the data base

---

Sample data row that would be within end-users file

```
24/01/2017,17:06,0.123,0.43,1.23,4,4.43,0.12
```

The digits are parameters, i map those out within importer to correct parameter names.

At the present moment, due to INLINE not able to handle foreign keys, I am referring to the "record_id" within "parameters" table, I am having to have two loops to import the file, as mentioned in above description.

1\ I would create measurements within PHP and grab id numbers.
2\ I will loop through the data file and create a file to import via INLINE for the "records" table; each row would also contain a json array of data with of parameters.
3\ I would loop through the "records" table and create new file to import via INLINE for the parameters in "parameters" table.

---

Shortened version of existing tables

```
CREATE TABLE `measurements` (
    `id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,  
    `measurement` ENUM('1','2') NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci',
)

CREATE TABLE `records` (
    `id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `measurement_id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `no` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `date` DATE NOT NULL,
    `time` TIME NOT NULL, 
    `params_temp` TEXT NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`), 
    INDEX `records_measurement_id_index` (`measurement_id`), 
    CONSTRAINT `records_measurement_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`measurement_id`) REFERENCES `measurements` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE, 
)

CREATE TABLE `params` (
    `id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `record_id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `parameter` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    `value` DOUBLE(8,2) NOT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    INDEX `params_record_id_index` (`record_id`), 
    CONSTRAINT `params_record_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`record_id`) REFERENCES `records` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
)
```

In records table 'params_temp' contains parameters that would later on be imported into "params" table. This happens by looping through newly added records within "records" table and creating new file to INLINE using "records.id" and "records.params_temp". "records.params_temp" would have json data with array of parameters.

Example of json data:

```
[{"parameter":"x","value":"27.33"},{"parameter":"y","value":"57.78"},{"parameter":"z","value":"5.105639E-06"}]
```

---

Example of files that I generate using PHP for import via INLINE

For Records:

For Params (record_id, param, value):

```
"19578952","x","-39.338954925537";
"19578954","y","-39.187381744385";
"19578956","z","-39.261814117432";
```

---

Longer version of existing tables

```
`measurements`:
- id int(10)
- file_id int(10)
- band enum(with 3 options)
- interval enum(with 2 options)
- frequency enum(with 3 options)
- weight enum(with 3 options)
- measurment_number enum(with 2 options)
- created_at (timestamp) (thinking to remove this)
- updated_at (timestamp) (thinking to remove this)
- owner_id int(10) (storing owner id for quick export/import of data belonging to the owner) 

`records`
- id int(10)
- measurement_id int(10)
- no int(11)
- date date
- time time
- ident varchar(255)
- created_at (timestamp) (thinking to remove this)
- updated_at (timestamp) (thinking to remove this)
- owner_id int(10) (storing owner id for quick export/import of data belonging to the owner)
- params_titles (text) (used to populate params tables)
- params_temp (text) (used to populate params tables)

`params`
- id int(10)
- record_id int(10)
- parameter varchar(255)
- value double(8,2)
- frequency varchar(255)
- created_at (thinking to remove this)
- updated_at (thinking to remove this)
- owner_id  (storing owner id for quick export/import of data belonging to the owner)
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53298/discussion-on-question-by-user3402600-when-3rd-nf-is-not-the-best-solution-per).

Comment: You say "shortened".  Please provide the other columns or at least indicate how many more columns are in each table.

Comment: I have added a longer version with some comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible, even inside a `LOAD DATA` statement to convert `24/01/2017,17:06` to a MySQL `DATETIME` (or `TIMESTAMP` or `INT`); there are some good examples in the docs.  But what if there is a mal-formed date; what do you want done then?

In that case it may be better to throw the data into a `VARCHAR`; move the valid rows to the target table(s), then send an email about the rest?

So, you want `0.123,0.43,1.23,4,4.43,0.12` to be turned into rows?  One row per measurement?  This would require putting the data in a tmp talbe before 'shredding'; `LOAD DATA` cannot handle it.  This may, or may not, be the best move.  What the subsequent `SELECTs` will be?

Since you are talking about large datasets, you need to keep the disk footprint small (for speed).  I question the need for `id` on many of the tables.  Do you have a 'natural' `PRIMARY KEY`?  If so, consider abandoning `id`.

I suggest the real question is about ultimate performance, not about textbook NF.  (Granted, there is some overlap.)

**Schema tips**

Do not use (m,n) on `DOUBLE`:  `DOUBLE(8,2)`.  That leads to a second rounding.  Either switch to `DECIMAL(8,2)` or use `FLOAT`/`DOUBLE`.  `FLOAT` takes 4 bytes (vs 8 for `DOUBLE`) and provides about 7 significant digits, probably sufficient for your measurements?

Hint (from experience):  In the long run you will very probably prefer a single `DATETIME` column over the clumsiness of two columns (`DATE` and `TIME`).

A one-byte ENUM is being replaced by a 4-byte INT?  There is no advantage in normalizing tiny columns.  An index on a 2-valued column will very probably *never* be used.

Please elaborate on the use of `params`; it smells like 'over-normalization`.

Comment: Rick, one thing you mentioned is "it smells like 'over-normalization`.". After a long time thinking about it, I have counted the number of columns that I need to add to the "records" table to merge "params" into "records" table and we are talking 200+ columns most of which would be blank. The thing that frightens me is that params and records tables are now holding 20GB each.. I can definitely see it grow to 1tb in next year or two and it brings up further questions how do we protect this date and prevent it from going corrupt?

Answer (score 2):

I have found that a good solution to problems like this is to pretend like you're interfacing with a 3rd party data source. Create a 4th table that is specifically designed to hold the data that is being imported.  A "staging table" so to speak.  It's designed specifically for the type of data you will be getting.  It has no foreign keys or any associations to any other objects in the database.  After the data has been accepted, a follow-up process to actually consume the data into your 3NF tables is started.  This process can do tricksy things like

```
INSERT INTO tab_a (id, col1, col2)
SELECT distinct (b.id, b.col1, b.col2) FROM tab_b AS b
LEFT JOIN tab_a AS a ON b.id = a.id
WHERE a.id IS NULL;
```

This usually makes the process much faster, and also splits it up into two logical steps.

Accept the uploaded file -> Process the uploaded file

Rick James points out that a more detailed description of this process (along with ways to handle various situations) can be found [here](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/data-warehousing-high-speed-ingestion/#normalization)